# Bunch of questions about View ids

Tags: android, view

i would like to ask a lot of questions about how this whole id system works in android. I looked up the View documentation, but the description was too shallow for my taste.

1. Is there a pattern, how the IDE (Eclipse/Netbeans) generates the ids
   when i use `android:id="@+id/..."`? Or is it completely random?
2. If i set ids programmatically, then will it be found by the Context
   classes `findViewById()` function?
3. If the answer for the previous question is yes, then if i want to
   create a large amount of Views, but i want them to have distinct ids
   for later identification, then wich one is better to use? (To answer
   this question, it would be really useful to know the answer for the
   first two)

   For example generating random ids in the largest possible range:

   ```
   Random random = new Random();
   for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
   {
       View view = new View(someContext);
       view.setId(random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
   }
   ```

   Or setting the ids in some sort of order, for example:

   ```
   final int addToId = 5670;
   for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
   {
       View view = new View(someContext);
       view.setId(i+addToId);
   }
   ```
4. Also i would like to know, what happens, when you use a
   LayoutInflater for example to populate a `ListView` using a
   pre-defined xml layout for every item in the list. Then you get your
   sub-views in the `getView()` function by the `findViewById()`. So i
   assume, that all the identical Views across your listitems have the
   same id. If so, then is it a good practice to use the `tag`
   attribute to distinguish the items in an inflated layout?

**Any clear explanation for these question would be highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. @+id/.... creates an id value that lives within the applications namespace. Contrast this with @android:id/.... which lives in the android namespace.
2. When you set the id in code and add the view element to the layout it will then become available to access through the code. You won't be able to reference it from the xml
3. Not sure you want to be using random to generate your ids? think sequential would be better but even then what is the point of a random id? How do you know which view you are referring to?
4. Definitely use the tag option and look to use the ViewHolder pattern for smoother list scrolling. You could add the id to the view holder class if you need access to it but it would be available anyway through the data set being used to populate the list. A quick search will give you plenty of examples for this.

Comment: Hi! the basic idea behind the random / increasing ids was to avoid somehow to add duplicate ids without manually looking up all the fix ids in the layout xml, and checking, if the new id is already among them. Thank you for the answer, but could you please tell me, how these ids are generated? As far as i can tell, like my second option: the IDE chooses a random number and adds one with each new id.

Comment: If you don't add an id then you won't be able to access the view by id. Have you looked at adding a tag to the view and then accessing by a tag? Is the option of iterating through the child views a possible solution to what you are trying to achieve? Generally you only need an id if you need to access a specific view in the hierarchy. If the view is a list or grid type parent then you will access the child views through an adapter class which will handle setting and retrieving the view in question. Maybe further information regarding the context of the question would help?

Comment: I have no specific in mind, what i'm trying to achieve. Truth is, that the question came up, when i wrote a wrapper class for RadioButtons, to create something similar like a RadioGroup without being a View, just handling the buttons check state. This class handles, selects and deselects the RadioButtons by id, and when i started testing it with larger amount of RadioButtons, i needed to generate ids dinamically. Then i started to wonder about these questions. Thanks for your help again, i think the most important to know was, that runtime generated ids are accessible by findViewById().